# Deploying Models with GCP

Tags: python

Is there a recommended architecture/design to run models using (Google Cloud Platform)GCP?

This is what I currently have

1. A data model and associated data in relational tables in BigQuery
2. A model formulation and associated helper functions/class in python. It uses the ortools library to build and solve the model.
3. An excel template for any inputs that are 'scenario specific' that aren't contained in BigQuery already.

I can run my model locally(reading input and writing output to BigQuery). I would like to take the next step by running a model anytime my 'template' is written to GCS. But am unsure if this can be implemented via a cloud function, or if I will need to use other services like Google Cloud Run.

Ideally, I will make things more productize overtime, like replacing the 'input template' with a gui that sends a json payload and triggers the run, but looking to understand if there is any generally recommended approach.

Comment: I don't think this question is suitable for OR.SE. You may get better luck posting it on StackOverflow.